# Async image gallery in React

Tags: reactjs, image, image-gallery

I am creating an image gallery in react. I am  loading all the thumbnails of the images on one page, rendering the array of images stored in the initial state with map().
What I would like to do is to load the image thumbnails in one by one (once the first loaded fade it in) and then the same with the second etc. like a domino effect. What is the best way to get around the problem?
I have tried to map the array and set an onload on the img tag but that just fades all the images in at once, once all are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fadein the image as soon as you load the image, you wont get the domino effect you want because you will load the images at different times. For example, maybe image 4 fadesin first, then image 6, then image 1, or maybe all the images load at once and fadein at the same time.

I recommend once all the images are loaded, you fadein image #1, delay 1 second, fadein image #2, delay 1 second, fadein image #3, to get your Domino effect.

Comment: Can I load first in and then fade it in, and then start loading the next? If yes how? At the moment my images are in this.state.ImageUrls and I am mapping through them like so: 
`ImageUrls.map((ImageUrl, index)=> { return (<div ><img key={index} id="thumbnail" onLoad={this.imageLoaded} src={ImageUrl} className={this.state.galleryContent} onClick={(e) => this.openModal(index, ImageUrl, e)}/></div>)})}`

Comment: Change to className=`${this.state.galleryContent} ${this.state.imageFadein[index] ? 'fadein' : ''}`. Then in your imageLoaded() function, detect when the last of all images are loaded, then perform your domino effect to fadein each subsequent image every second via setTimeout(function() { this.setState({ this.state.imageFadein[0]: true }); setTimeout(function() { this.setState({ this.state.imageFadein[1]: true }); }, 1000); }, 1000);

Comment: your this.state.galleryContent should have opacity: 0, and the fadein class is just a simply opacity change: .fadein { animation: fadein 2s; } @keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }

Comment: Do you mean this.setState({ imageFadein[0]: true }); and not this.setState({ this.state.imageFadein[0]: true }); and am I thinking wrong but do you mean creating a new state called imageFadein and mutating its state, not with with my existing ImageUrls where I have my images?

Comment: I have created the new state. Which stores the fadein true or false, which will set the classname, but I get an error in the imageLoaded function `this.setState({ imageFadein[0]: true });` hmmm

Comment: Sorry yes i mean "this.setState({ imageFadein[0]: true })". The setState function probably cant find that index. Im not sure how many images are in your gallery but when you initialize your state you should set all the image's fadein state to false: this.state = { ..., imageFadein: [false, false, false, ...]}